# Push to new view controller only if textfields are correct

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Currently using Xcode 4.2 and I have two view controllers (1 and 2). I have a number of textfields in viewcontroller1 that need to be filled in before the user is able to click the "Next" button which then goes to viewcontroller2. I have got alertdialogs that popup if the user hasn't filled in all the textfields.

I have used the storyboard to segue the button click which works fine, except if the textfields are empty, my alertdialog pops up but the view controller still changes to number 2.

How do i make it so that only if my if/else statements are met, does the next button go to the next view controller.

I am using a navigation controller to control the view controllers.

I tried to put the following code into the if/else statement but it didn't work:

```
UIViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewControllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"<name of xib>" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

Now there was a few things I was unsure about when trying to find out how to use this method. Do i need to import the SecondViewController.m at the top of the firstviewcontroller.m?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSString has a helpful property called `length`, which will return nil if a textfield contains no text.  If you need to check, call:

```
if (!myTextField.text.length) { 
    //no text in the box
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough, since you have already set up the alert boxes to pop up if something is wrong with the textbox input, make sure the alert box show/init code is before the code that changes the view and do this:

```
if(//something is wrong with the textbox input)
{
    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWith...
    [alert show];

    //Add a return! If the method is not IBAction or void, just return nil
    return;
}
```

Voila!

Comment: Thanks, but i can't tell if that helps, because I can't get the code to get the view controller to go to the next view controller. Why wouldn't that code above work to get the new controller open?

Comment: All I'm really saying to do is add a return in your code where you determine that there is an error. That way, if everything checks out, it should still make it to the point where you initialize the new view and present it. As for your code that presents it, I don't see anything that could make it not work other than you are trying to present it with an animation but you never specify an animation. Other than that which really shouldn't be a problem, I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: Is there a problem if the navigation controller and all other 'pushed' are done via the storyboard, and then I am trying to do it through code only with this one viewcontroller? Is there anything I need to import or declare in the .h or .m files that would normally be done by the storyboard?

Comment: Not that I know of. Typically I don't like storyboards because of small issues like this, but running straight code would not affect performance.